# plural and singular agreement of nouns

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Sentence in question :

> Claims about harmful effects of the genetic alteration of vegetables are more speculation than documented fact.

Should the nouns *speculation* and *fact* be plural because they refer to the plural claims?

Comment: No. Grammmatically you could make a case for (optionally) using plurals there, but stylistically I'd say singular is better. I might put the indefinite article before "harmful effects" rather than "genetic", but it's all just stylistic choices.

Comment: Compare *Claims about **the** harmful effects of cellphone radiation are more speculation than documented fact.* You wouldn't move the article there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plurals would be grammatically correct, but there is nothing wrong with the sentence as such.  As FumbleFingers mentioned, its just style!